# Hibernate ManyToMany through join table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I just started learning Hibernate, I just go through examples in book and there is something strange with ManyToMany relationship example, here is code:

Left side of the relationship

```
package com.examscm.mappings;

import com.examscm.HibernateUtil;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by me on 20.06.15.
*/

@Entity
@Table(schema = "HibernateBook")
public class LeftManyStudents {

private long id;
private String studentName;
List<RightManyCourses> courses = new ArrayList<>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = RightManyCourses.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "join_table", schema = "HibernateBook",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "lmstudent_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "rmcourse_id")})
public List<RightManyCourses> getCourses(){
    return courses;
}

public void setCourses(List<RightManyCourses> courses){
    this.courses = courses;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    HibernateUtil.recreateDatabase();
    /*Creating and saving instances of left and right side
      side of relationship*/
}
}
```

Right side of relationship:

```
package com.examscm.mappings;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by me on 20.06.15.
*/

@Entity
@Table(schema = "HibernateBook")
public class RightManyCourses {

private long id;
private String courseCode;
List<LeftManyStudents> students = new ArrayList<>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCourseCode() {
    return courseCode;
}

public void setCourseCode(String courseCode) {
    this.courseCode = courseCode;
}

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = LeftManyStudents.class,
cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "join_table", schema = "HibernateBook",
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "rmcourse_id")},
inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "lmstudent_id")}
)
public List<LeftManyStudents> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public void setStudents(List<LeftManyStudents> students){
    this.students = students;
}
}
```

And recreate database code:

```
public static void recreateDatabase(){
    Configuration configuration = getInitializedConfiguration();
    new SchemaExport(configuration).create(true, true);
}
```

The problem is, when there is default Class to Column name mapping, everythink works fine, but when i change it for example like that:

```
@Table(name = "left_many_students", schema = "HibernateBook")
@Table(name = "right_many_courses", schema = "HibernateBook")
```

I got following error

```
cze 20, 2015 10:21:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Table 'HibernateBook.join_table' doesn't exist
```

So I created it manually and then next error:

```
cze 20, 2015 10:23:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table HibernateBook.join_table drop foreign key FK_22m6gyyey9mu21mlfbge6uguj
cze 20, 2015 10:23:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Can't DROP 'FK_22m6gyyey9mu21mlfbge6uguj'; check that column/key exists
cze 20, 2015 10:23:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table HibernateBook.player drop foreign key FK_5q11flfd61t4n9eepixi8ltup
cze 20, 2015 10:23:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Can't DROP 'FK_5q11flfd61t4n9eepixi8ltup'; check that column/key exists
```

But it is really strange, because if I just remove @Entity from this two clases and recreate database everythink works fine, no foreign key errors.

I have no idea what's the problem, could anyone tell me ?

Comment: I never use Hibernate to generate my schema, so I don't know if it's related, but your mapping is wrong. One of the sides must be the inverse side of the other side, and thus not have any JoinTable annotation, but use @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses") (or @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students" depending on which one you choose). Also, the name chosen for the entities is awful. Don't use the plural form. Just name them Student and Course.

Comment: Well, You are right, book is wrong, now I am still getting SQL Errors when I create schema from scratch ( because Hibernate tries to drop foreign keys on no existing tables ), but It creates properly . And when I recreate it, there is no errors. Thank You.